# Concurrent collection for storing objects

Tags: java, caching, collections

I need to find a proper collection that matches:

- One writer, many readers (collection should be threadsafe)
- Cheap iteration
- Should preserve order in which records have been inserted
- Size restriction:

  - Fixed size - when threshold achieved each time new record is being inserted the most old one should be deleted
  - Or time threshold - something like 'only records that not olrder than 5 hrs' should be kept

I am pretty sure that this problem isn't something new and probably some cache could be used for these purposes?

Comment: if you're to develop a Web Application, give a try to [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) for a caching solution.

Comment: So close... `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` does all of these except size restriction.

Comment: You can just wrap a ConcurrentLinkedQueue around a ReadWriteLock and be happy.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [Guava's cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/package-summary.html) package.  If you look at [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), it includes most of the features you specify.  I don't know about ordering preservation (why do you want that?)

The underlying collection (can't tell from your question/title if you're looking for a complete cache implementation or a collection that would support it) is probably [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html?is-external=true).